# facebook android call function does not work after facebook login

Tags: java, android, facebook

I am trying to make a simple app in which when the user logins the facebook, the user's name is displayed in the textview. The problem is that textview does not change. I think there is some problem with the call back function. This is the code for the MainActivity. Regards

```
     package com.example.firstfacebook;
        import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.facebook.Request;
import com.facebook.Response;
import com.facebook.Session;
import com.facebook.SessionState;
import com.facebook.model.GraphUser;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       // TextView welcome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.welcome);
        //welcome.setText("Hello!");
        // start Facebook Login
        Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

          // callback when session changes state
          @Override
          public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
            if (session.isOpened()) {


              // make request to the /me API
              Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                // callback after Graph API response with user object
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                  if (user != null) {
                    TextView welcome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.welcome);
                    welcome.setText("Hello " + user.getName() + "!");
                  }
                }
              });
            }
          }
        });
      }
      /*public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
        }*/

      @Override
      public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
          super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
          Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode,
                  resultCode, data);
      }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I am using android `simple Facebook library` project for login and posting.You don't have to call any callback method externally. This library take care of all callbacks. You might be interested in this [sample](https://github.com/sromku/android-simple-facebook) project made using this library. Just have a look at it.

I hope this will use full to you.